# Sending messages from SharedWorker to SharedWorker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

The [MDN Documentation on SharedWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) states:

> The SharedWorker interface represents a specific kind of worker that can be accessed from several browsing contexts, such as several windows, iframes **or even workers**.

To me this sounds as if SharedWorkers should be able to directly exchange messages. However, if I try to access a SharedWorker from within another SharedWorker, namely with

```
var worker = new SharedWorker("path/to/file.js");
```

I get

> ReferenceError: SharedWorker is not defined

Did I just misread the documentation, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Dedicated workers are different from shared workers as stated by that very page. What you emphasized is referring to dedicated workers and not shared workers. So yep, you misread the documentation ;) I don't really know of any other way to do this, and I don't see any real use case of why I would like to do this. (But I guess you are just asking this out of curiosity which is ok ofcourse).

Comment: I'm having a multi window application that was supposed to use SharedWorkers in kind of a pipeline architecture, without having to redirect messages between pipeline steps through a browser window again. So yeah, there are use cases for that.

Comment: "kind of a pipeline"? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Going into the details would be beyond the scope of all this, but I'm sure you know the [Pipeline Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28software%29). That's what I was trying to implement with SharedWorkers.

Comment: _"ReferenceError: SharedWorker is not defined"_ Was `worker.port.start()` called ?

Comment: Can include text of `"path/to/file.js"` at Question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you don't seem to be able to create a shared worker from a shared worker, you can communicate between them by creating them in the main thread, and passing the `MessagePort` object of one to the other. Note you have to include the port in the transfer list argument to `postMessage`: it can't be copied.

For example, in the main thread create the workers, and send the port of one to the other:

```
var myWorker1 = new SharedWorker("worker1.js");
myWorker1.port.start();

var myWorker2 = new SharedWorker("worker2.js");
myWorker2.port.start();

myWorker2.port.postMessage({worker1Port: myWorker1.port}, [myWorker1.port]);
```

In the first worker you can send messages on a port:

```
self.onconnect = function(e) {
  var port = e.ports[0];

  self.setInterval(function() {
    port.postMessage('sent from worker 1');
  }, 1000);
};
```

and then in the second worker you can save the incoming port object, and respond to messages received on it.

```
self.onconnect = function(e) {
  var port = e.ports[0];

  port.onmessage = function(e) {
    var worker1Port = e.data.worker1Port;
    worker1Port.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log('received in worker 2', e.data);
    };
  };
};
```

You can see this working at http://plnkr.co/edit/XTOej1b1PHfWuC9LHeZc?p=preview

Comment: That looks very promising. Thanks for your answer. I'll try it as soon as I have the chance.