# Postmessage using Sharedworker

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-worker, shared-worker

With given tsconfig.json,

```
{

    "compilerOptions": {

      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    },
    "files": [
      "./1_webworker/tstut.ts",
      "./1_webworker/worker.ts"

    ]
  }
```

and [folder structure](https://github.com/shamhub/shamhub.github.io)

---

Ran `npm install --save @types/sharedworker`.

In below code(from `./1_webworker/tstut.ts`),

`let worker: Worker = new Worker('worker.js');`

to use sharedworker syntax, declared:

`let worker: SharedWorker.SharedWorker = new SharedWorker('worker.js');`

but below is the error.

```
worker.postMessage('do some work'); // Property 'postMessage' does not exist on type 'SharedWorker'

worker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {

  console.log(e.data); // Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event'
});
```

How to post a message string to sharedworker?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example of `SharedWorker` in TypeScript.

*caller.ts*

```
let worker = new SharedWorker('worker.js');
worker.port.start();

worker.port.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Caller Received:', e.data);
}

worker.port.postMessage('Message');
```

*worker.ts*

```
interface SharedWorkerGlobalScope {
    onconnect: (event: MessageEvent) => void;
}

const _self: SharedWorkerGlobalScope = self as any;

_self.onconnect = function (e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];

    port.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log('Worker Received', e.data);
        port.postMessage('Result');
    });

    port.start(); // Required when using addEventListener. Otherwise called implicitly by onmessage setter.
}
```

The `SharedWorkerGlobalScope` is currently part of the type definition you have pulled from npm. I will submit a pull request to update it shortly.

Comment: [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker#Example) has `postMessage()` for sharedworker. Query edited

Comment: I see `postMessage` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30704054/3317808). Probably am using in a wrong way, without using port. Not sure, about port.

Comment: See updated answer, and pull request: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/26202

Comment: A supple question: Sir, Can I `postMessage()` a shared worker in cross domain?With dedicated webworker I can